# Why does the partial of $f: \Delta \to \mathbb{R}^2$ fail to exist?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definition, jacobian

Given $f: \Delta = \{x = (x_1,x_2)| x_1+x_2 = 1, x_1 \geq 0, x_2 \geq 0\} \to \mathbb{R}^2$

**Claim: $\dfrac{\partial f_i}{ \partial x_j}$ doesn't exist.**

**This statement is true.** Can anyone please provide a way to justify this statement?

I have a feeling that this is due to compactness of the domain of $f$, which comes into conflict with the formal definition of the partial derivative. But I do not know if we could extend the definition of partial derivative for $f$ defined on compact sets. Further, I can produce large amount of examples that seems to contradict the claim:

Example: Consider $f(x_1,x_2) = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ 2 x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} f_1 \\ f_2 \end{bmatrix}$, then clearly $\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} = 1, \dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} = 0$, ditto the other partials.

Can anyone please assist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of $f$ is a line segment that contains no open interval in the $x_1$ or $x_2$ direction. So the idea of a derivative in these directions, which is what the partial derivatives of $f$ would be, is dead on arrival.

Comment: Hi could you clarify what you mean? I agree that the domain contains no open interval in the $x_1$ or $x_2$ direction, but I do not see how that implies that the derivative will not exist. Could you provide an analogous example that maybe simpler to visualize? And also why does my example not work?

Comment: @StrayCat  How can it be made clearer? The domain is the line segment from $(0,1)$ to $(1,0).$ It seems to me obvious that the partial derivatives cannot even be considered on such a domain. The example you gave doesn't really make sense since the domain is not $\Delta$ in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x_1 + x_2 = 1$ on $\Delta$, we can write $f(x_1,x_2)= (x_1, 2x_2) = (1 - x_2, 2x_2)$ and thus "clearly" $\dfrac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} = 0$. Do you see a problem? You need to think about more than just the rule you use to define the function to assess its differentiability - go back to the actual definition of partial derivatives and work out what's really going on here.